# Insert text n lines before the end of file

Tags: python-3.x, text-manipulation

I have this file and I would like to be able to write text `n` lines before the end of the file in python, I know the write method exists however it only inserts text at the very end of the file. I would like to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12749", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12755", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12757", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12765", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12774", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12785", "1", "0");

/* I would like to be able to insert some text here with python/*

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; 

/* Duplicator WordPress Timestamp: 2021-01-08 15:49:50*/
/* DUPLICATOR_MYSQLDUMP_EOF */
```

`/* DUPLICATOR_MYSQLDUMP_EOF */` being the very last line of the file, thanks very much in advance! Also I use python 3.8.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could approach this problem is to read the file into a list of lines. Insert your new line into which ever position you want. Then write that list of lines out to a new file.

If you know the line number to insert you could use that position directly. If you need to calculate the line position based on number of lines from bottom of file, you can calculate the line position as the difference between the total number of lines and your number N.

That could look something like this:

```
    # Insert text n lines before the end of file

    file_path = 'text.txt'
    line_to_insert = '/*this is my inserted line*/\n'
    lines_from_bottom = 4

    with open(file_path) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        insert_position = len(lines) - lines_from_bottom
        lines.insert(insert_position, line_to_insert)
        with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as new_file:
            for line in lines:
                new_file.write(line)
```

Comment: worked like a charm for me, thanks a lot and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many lines you have to skip starting from the end, just split your source text line by line, add the new text and then re-join:

```py
source_text = '''INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12749", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12755", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12757", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12765", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12774", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12785", "1", "0");

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; 

/* Duplicator WordPress Timestamp: 2021-01-08 15:49:50*/
/* DUPLICATOR_MYSQLDUMP_EOF */'''

custom_text = "my new cool text"
lines_before = 5 # you want to add the new text 5 lines before the end

lines = source_text.split('\n')
lines.insert(-lines_before, "\n" + custom_text)
new_text = "\n".join(lines)

print(new_text)
```

---

Otherwise, you can use regular expressions for this:

```py
import re

source_text = '''INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12749", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12755", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12757", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12765", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12774", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12785", "1", "0");

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; 

/* Duplicator WordPress Timestamp: 2021-01-08 15:49:50*/
/* DUPLICATOR_MYSQLDUMP_EOF */'''

custom_text = "my new cool text"
new_text = re.sub("\s+(?=SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS)", "\n\n%s\n\n" % custom_text, source_text)

print(new_text)
```

---

Both methods will print:

```
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12749", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12755", "0", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12757", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12765", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12774", "1", "0");
INSERT INTO `mod238_yoast_seo_meta` VALUES("12785", "1", "0");

my new cool text

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;

/* Duplicator WordPress Timestamp: 2021-01-08 15:49:50*/
/* DUPLICATOR_MYSQLDUMP_EOF */
```

Clearly, instead of printing it, you have to overwrite the input file (or create a new one) with the content of `new_text` variable.

Comment: I really like the idea of using regex as i'm pretty unexperienced when it comes to that, I wil give it a serious look thank you for your time